# RPC: Timed out error when portmap is running

Tags: c++, c, linux, rpc

When I try to register an application using the following, I receive an "RPC: Timed out" error

```
if (!svc_register(transp, AVERAGEPROG, AVERAGEVERS, averageprog_1, IPPROTO_TCP)) {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s", "unable to register (AVERAGEPROG, AVERAGEVERS, tcp).");
    exit(1);                                                                  
}
```

I have restarted the portmap service, however this did not help matters. Also, I checked to ensure that I do not have a hosts.deny file in place, so I know connections are not being blocked here. Using

```
rpcinfo -p <host>
```

I get the following output:

```
program vers proto   port
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
```

indicating that portmap is running as it should. Is there something I am missing that causes portmap to block incoming RPC applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by enabling the loopback interface through ifconfig using:

```
$ ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1
```

Portmap seems to require this in order to map RPC applications.